Can I cut the inner plastic behind the drywall on an outer wall?
I cut a piece of drywall from an outer wall to run ethernet. When I did that I noticed I had cut through plastic that was right behind the drywall, between it and the insulation. Is that problematic? Do I need to do anything special before I reinstall and patch the drywall panel I cut out?

This is a vapor barrier, designed to prevent condensation on the insulation and structure on the cold side of the barrier.
Ideally, you can repair it by cutting back the drywall a little  to expose the plastic and apply a new piece of plastic over the existing. Secure in place with  silicone sealant or a seaming tape used for house wrap.
